# Facebook scraper not validating og:image url

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am running some functions on my controller to come up with a custom meta tag url that is then taken and used on the opengraph image tag for facebook. This image gets put in a variable, that then gets displayed on a url used for scraping on facebook. I got it working the right way and now the linter comes back at me with this error.

Object at URL 'http://mypage.org/pages/post.html?PostID=9192&prog=' of type 'website' is invalid because the given value '' for property 'og:image:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'.

How is that not a valid url? I can take the link and put it in my browser and it comes up just fine. I notice as well when I go down to see the scraped url it gives me back this..

```
<meta property="og:image" content="&lt;img src='http://www.mypage.org/images/post_images/4121.jpg' /&gt;">
```

Looks like it takes my < and />, makes them into hex..why would the scraper do this? Btw here is the code from my controller.

```
$img = strstr($img, '<img src=');
$substring = substr($img, 0, strpos($img, "/>"));
$img = $substring . "/>";
```

What this code does is I take the code before the  to the end of the url making a full `<img src = "" />` url. Any and all help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing there, shouldn't it just be `<meta property="og:image" content='http://www.usa-gymnastics.org/images/post_images/4121.jpg"/>` ?
`

Comment: Yes, it should be! Thank you. I don't know why I didn't realize this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You shouldn't embed the HTML tag into the content of the meta tag. Try this format instead:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.mypage.org/images/post_images/4121.jpg">
```

Answer (score 4):

The content of your meta property should be the URL for the image, not a DOM  element.
Replace your og:image meta property by this one and it should work:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.mypage.org/images/post_images/4121.jpg">
```