# Facebook pixelates shared Blogger posts

Tags: facebook, thumbnails, blogger

When I share a post on Facebook from my blog, the thumbnail is pixelated.

The photos are bigger than 200 X 200.

I get this error message on Facebook's Object Debugger:  Object at URL 'http://www.nameofmyblog.com/' of type 'article' is invalid because a required property 'og:image:url' of type 'url' was not provided.

Any suggestions?﻿

Comment: Does your page actually have an `og:image` reference? Could you possibly share with us the actual URL?

Comment: Does this previous question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606272/facebook-scraper-not-validating-ogimage-url